# Exclude directories that contain a certain file type with rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I would like rsync to skip entire directories if they contain a certain file type.

I'm aware of how to exclude files of a certain type. But since I don't know all the types of files I want to exclude, just that if one type exists the whole dir should be excluded, that is not of much help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go this way:

- build a file listing all files:
  `find . > allfiles`
- get the list of directories not to be rsynced. Since you did not specify what is your criterium, let's assume it is a file suffix like `fop`

  `find .  -path '*fop' | xargs -r -n1 dirname`

would give you the list of "forbidden directories". Here you have to adapt to your case.

- then `grep -v` the forbidden directories from the whole file list, building a filtered file list
- then rsync with `--files-from=` switch using the filtered file list

Comment: It should be possible to get the same result without creating the list of all files and filtering it; simply pass the forbidden directories to rsync as a list (with `--exclude`) or file (with `--exclude-from`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is kind of ugly, but you can always throw in backticks and run a find command with some sed work in it. For example, if I want to ignore all directories that have a file with the extension `.dist`, then I can do this:

```
rsync -vvaR `find /etc -name '*.dist' | sed -e 's:/[^/]*$:/:' | sort | uniq | sed -e 's:^/:--exclude /:'` /etc rsync://hostname.com/
```

I get some output that looks like:

```
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/bash/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/bind/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/conf.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/cron.daily/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/eclean/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/init.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/logrotate.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/modprobe.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/mysql/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/pam.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/portage/bin/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/portage/postsync.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/portage/savedconfig/sys-apps/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/profile.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/security/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/ssh/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/ssl/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/ssl/certs/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/ssl/misc/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/ssmtp/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/syslog-ng/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/udev/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/udev/rules.d/)
[client] add_rule(- /etc/config-archive/etc/vim/)
opening tcp connection to hostname.com port 873
```